# import djangorestframework fails after installing it

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to run a Django project (Mayan EDMS) in Apache. From a Ubuntu 12.10, Apache 2.2.22, Python 2.7.3 and Django (1, 4, 3, 'final', 0).

When I go to the served web it fails and shows me errors in the apache log, they are all errors concerning modules in Python that are not installed, I install the modules and errors changed from one module to other:

```
sudo easy_install django-pagination
sudo easy_install South
sudo easy_install requests
sudo easy_install mptt
```

It all seems to go fine till a module named `djangorestframework` is needed. I install it successfully:

```
pip install djangorestframework
```

but it's still not found:

```
[Mon Dec 24 20:15:29 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 86, in load_app
[Mon Dec 24 20:15:29 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     app_module = import_module(app_name)
[Mon Dec 24 20:15:29 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
[Mon Dec 24 20:15:29 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     __import__(name)
[Mon Dec 24 20:15:29 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImportError: No module named djangorestframework
```

When I run manually python in shell and I make an import of the previous installed modules (`requests`, `mptt`) everything is ok, but I cannot import a `djangorestframework` module.

```
>>> import djangorestframework
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named djangorestframework
>>>
```

After reading the [how to install `djangorestframework`](http://django-rest-framework.org/#installation)  I see that when it's declared in `INSTALLED_APPS` it's declared as **`rest_framework`**, I try to `import rest_framework` in python and it accepts it successfully. I guessed that I only had to rename the reference to the module in the Django source. The problem is that I found lots of mentions of it in the files and I intuit it's not a good idea.

what can I be doing wrong? The installation is so simple, I encourage readers just to install the module

```
pip install djangorestframework
```

and try to import it in Python

```
import djangorestframework
```

I've tried it in two computers and same problem occurred (both computers have the same Ubuntu/Apache/Django configuration).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's installed in site-packages/rest_framework, so you should use:

```
import rest_framework
```

Comment: using rest_framework in the INSTALLED_APPS worked for me